# Use StreamReader with GetFolderPath()?

Tags: c#, streamreader

I have a line to get the file path of a text file:

```
string file = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath
    (Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "file.txt");
```

Which returns:

```
file = "C:\\Users\\Benjamin\\AppData\\Roaming\\file.txt"
```

However, when I try and use a StreamReader on it, it returns a `FileNotFound` exception

```
StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(file); // Throws the FileNotFound exception.
```

Does the fact that the original location is different to the one returned? (Original location: `C:\Users\Benjamin\Documents\file.txt`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that `C:\Users\Benjamin\AppData\Roaming\file.txt` does not exist.

If you want `C:\Users\Benjamin\Documents\file.txt`, use `Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments` instead of `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData`

Comment: Ahh perfect! Thanks so much. It seems a bit strange that it was creating a file path when none existed...

Comment: As MatteoSp pointed out, `Path.Combine` does not not check if the file exists or "create" a file path. In general, it just concatenates the arguments with the directory separator character (backslash on Windows) and gives you the resulting string.

Answer (score 1):

Path.Combine just builds a path, it does not check if the file exists nor does anything if the file does not exists.

You're just trying to open a file that does not exists, as the exception says.

Comment: So why is it returning a different path?

Comment: As I stated in the question, the file path returned from the `Path.Combine()` method is different from the actual file path.

Comment: Path.Combine() knows nothing about no files, it just takes two strings and combine them in a single one.